# ASLA Audio Default Device Issue

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I am trying to get google-aiy assistant to run on my system. 
I have been having heaps of trouble getting the mic to work. I am pretty close I think, but I need some help.

For google assistant to work, I believe it requires the default mic to be set correctly. As I have it now, I have card 0 device 0 as the mic, and card 1 device 0 as the speaker.

I can run:

```
arecord -vv -D plughw:0 -r 48000 test.wav
```

And it records no problem, with the following output

```
Recording WAVE 'test.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
Plug PCM: Rate conversion PCM (16000, sformat=S16_LE)
Converter: libspeex (external)
Protocol version: 10002
Its setup is:
  stream       : CAPTURE
  access       : RW_INTERLEAVED
  format       : U8
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 1
  rate         : 48000
  exact rate   : 48000 (48000/1)
  msbits       : 8
  buffer_size  : 24000
  period_size  : 6000
  period_time  : 125000
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 6000
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 1
  stop_threshold   : 24000
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 1572864000
Slave: Hardware PCM card 0 'HP Webcam 2100' device 0 subdevice 0
Its setup is:
  stream       : CAPTURE
  access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
  format       : S16_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 1
  rate         : 16000
  exact rate   : 16000 (16000/1)
  msbits       : 16
  buffer_size  : 8000
  period_size  : 2000
  period_time  : 125000
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 2000
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 0
  stop_threshold   : 8000
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 2097152000
  appl_ptr     : 0
  hw_ptr       : 0
# +                                                | 20%
```

However when I try to run it without calling the device directly, I get different output and no audio input.

```
 arecord -vv -r 48000 test.wav


Recording WAVE 'test.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
ALSA <-> PulseAudio PCM I/O Plugin
Its setup is:
  stream       : CAPTURE
  access       : RW_INTERLEAVED
  format       : U8
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 1
  rate         : 48000
  exact rate   : 48000 (48000/1)
  msbits       : 8
  buffer_size  : 24000
  period_size  : 6000
  period_time  : 125000
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  tstamp_type  : GETTIMEOFDAY
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 6000
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 1
  stop_threshold   : 24000
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 1572864000
#+                                                 | 00%
```

Comment: How did you configure PulseAudio? What device does the assistant actually try to use?

Comment: Pulse Audio is installed, but I haven't done any configuration. That's the thing, I don't understand why it tries to access pulse audio when I don't specify a card and device number.

Comment: Because PulseAudio sets the `default` device to refer to PulseAudio.

Comment: okay, is there a way to undo that? I don't need PA. I've tried uninstalling it, but that generates a different set of error messages.